# How to create an enum dependent on another enum in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongoose, schema

I have the following schema:

```js
const doctorSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
{
    specialty: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    subspecialty: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    }
}
```

A doctor can have a single *specialty*. For example, a doctor can be a cardiologist or a neurologist.

A doctor can have a single *subspecialty*, but this is dependent on the original specialty. For example, a neurologist can have a subspecialty in neurocritical care, but a cardiologist cannot have a subspecialty in neurocritical care.

I am trying to model this in the schema. We can create a schema for specialties:

```js
enum specialty {
    cardiologist = 'cardiologist',
    neurologist = 'neurologist'
}
```

With this, how can I add an enum for subspecialties for each specialty? In other words, I would like to add a list of subspecialties that belong to ONLY a neurologist, a list that only belongs to ONLY cardiologists, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose has several built-in validators.

- All SchemaTypes have the built-in required validator. The required validator uses the SchemaType's checkRequired() function to determine if the value satisfies the required validator.
- Numbers have min and max validators.
- Strings have enum, match, minlength, and maxlength validators.

For your case you could do something like this

```
const doctorSchema = Schema({
 _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
specialty: { type: string, required: true }, 
subspecialty: { 
      type: string, 
      required: function() { 
        if(this.specialty === "neurologist"){
            return {
                enum : ['neurologist-sub-list','neurologist-sub-list2'],
                default: 'neurologist-sub-list',
                message: '{VALUE} is not supported'
             }
        }
      }
  } 
});
```

*you can do the remaining part in the if else block where specailty doesn't satisfy the neurologist*